# Making multiple requests on a single https connection using retrofit2

Tags: android, performance, retrofit, okhttp, android-networking

I want to upload a large file to my server but i want the ability to pause and resume the upload in middle. So to achieve this I am breaking the file into several chunks and sending them one by one. I am using retrofit for uploading the file chunks. It is a https request.

The problem with this approach is for individual chunk, a new connection is getting created due to which there is a certain overhead of creating a new connection, handshaking etc. with each request.

What I want is a way to send consecutive requests to the server using the same http connection. That connection should have a certain timeout.

Is it possible to achieve using retrofit2?

Answer (score 0):

One word... Multipart Request.

oh wait thats two, but that'll solve your problem. Your approach is incorrect.

Edit:[here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)  and [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-how-to-upload-files) is a post that might be helpful.

Comment: I couldn't understand can you please elaborate

Comment: hmm, let me see if i can dig up a few links..
basically its just FileUpload but using multipart format...so file is uploaded in pieces in one singular connection which can be paused and resumed depending on connection & socket timmeouts.

Comment: Even if there is a possibility to pause and resume a connection I have to solve one more use case i.e. app is closed somehow or killed than the connection will be aborted and in that case I do not want to restart my upload from beginning.

Comment: whoa, not sure if youll get a silver bullet solution for that, but it would require a change/communication logic with your server (or backend) as well as frontend.
Retrofit is a http client, not a DL manager, but anything can be leveraged with the right framework setup at both backend and frontend,...good luck!

Comment: already got the backend ready for this and its working fine. I just want to tweak its performance

Comment: well thats good, i meant the backend/frontend communication for resuming incomplete file uploads...that sounds pretty tricky. but then again it is one of your usecases. I hope my answer atleast pointed you in the right direction.